# How to write a procfile that changes directory and respects rbenv?

Tags: ruby, rbenv, foreman, procfile

**Given** two directories: `/a` and `/b`

**And** `/a/.ruby-version` has `2.0.0-p353`

**And** `/b/.ruby-version` has `jruby-1.7.9`

**And** the following `/a/Procfile`

```
a: ruby --version
b: sh -c 'cd /b && ruby --version'
```

**When** I `cd /a` and run `foreman run b`

**Then** I should see `jruby 1.7.9 .. etc` but instead I see `2.0.0-p353`

Answer (score 2):

With the proper sudo permisions, you can do:

```
b: sudo -u $USER bash -l -c "cd /b && ruby --version"
```

It's the safest way I know of.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but it didn't work for me.  It outputs my system ruby version, *not* the version specified by `/b/.ruby-version`.

Comment: I have just tested it and it works again. Maybe you've got a different problem preventing it from working?